# Modelica: Import Variable of other model

Tags: modelica

I try to write a model (fix), where I want to use a variable of a different model(room): The variable is called: room.Temp.
If I use in the model "fix" the variable: room.Temp --> i get an error message: Use of undeclared variable room.Temp.

Do I have to import the variables in my model "fix" ?
Thanx for your help

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the `inner`/`outer` keywords might be of use.

I don't know the exact details and purpose of your model but i assume that `room.Temp` represents a room temperature that should be known by other components in you overall model.

For instance, you could take a look at any of the examples in `Modelica.Fluid.Examples`. Here you will see that the `system` (lower case 's') model defined as an `inner` instance of the class `Modelica.Fluid.System` - a model that holds a number of general variables (ambient pressure and temperature etc.) that should be known by the other components in the examples.

Many of the components in Modelica.Fluid require an `outer` instance of the class `System` - and it should be named `system`. See for instance `Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialTwoPort`.

You apply the `inner` keyword when you instantiate your model (in Dymola, drag it to the canvas, right-click, select `View Attributes` and tick off `Inner`).

In your case, if your `Fix` class refers to an outer instance named 'room', you should be sure that you only have **one** instance of the `Room` class and that it is called `room` (not `room1`, `room_1` or whatever). Annotations `defaultComponentName`, `defaultComponentPrefixes` and `missingInnerMessage` in the `Room` class can help you with that (see the annotations in `Modelica.Fluid.System`).

Best regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how advanced solution you need, but the simplest one I can see is the following, where I assume your models look like this:

```
model Room
  Real temp;
end Room;
model Fix
  Real room_temp /* = ... Room.temp*/;
end Fix;

model Combined
  Room room;
  Fix fix;
end Combined;
```

Then add "input" in front of "room_temp" and change a line to:

```
Fix fix(room_temp=room.temp);
```

Changing room_temp to a connector make this more graphical.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you have not instantiated the model of "room" within the "fix" model. could you add your code here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have 2 complete seperate models (room and fix) that I drag into a blank model - One possibility would be to define the variable "Temp" in "room", which i need in "fix" as an real-output and connect it to "fix". But there should be an easier way right? So what does instantiate mean, and how do I implement it?

Comment: "Classes" and "instances" are terms from object-oriented programming: your models `Room` and `Fix` are "classes" when you drag them into a blank model they are instantiated (and probably named `room` and `fix`). If you drag more of them into your model you will have several uniquely named instances of your classes. If you make changes to the class the changes will immediately be reflected in all the instances.

Comment: it would be much easier to answer your question if you add your code or an example of what your are doing.